# Python Output to Table

Tags: python

I have the following snippet of code:

```
techs = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9"];

for tech in techs:
    current_tech = get_ticket_count(FHD_start,BHN_end,tech)
    tech_total =  str(current_tech[0])
    tech_average = current_tech[1]
    print "\n"
    print (tech)
    print "Total: " + tech_total
    print "Average: " + tech_average
```

The output looks like:

```
name1
Total: 69
Average: 17

name2
Total: 30
Average: 7

name3
Total: 0
Average: 0
```

...... and so on.

The end goal is to email the results in a table, but right now I'm trying to figure out how to properly output that to a table. Something like:

```
Tech  | Total | Average
name1 |  69   | 17
name2 |  30   | 7
name3 |  0    | 0
```

or just something organized like that. I'm not sure where to start. The articles and answers I've found all have to do with CSVs which I'm not reading from.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to use csv? That's just a plaintext way of storing a table with whatever separator you want.

Comment: You would need to ensure your email uses a fixed width font.

Comment: Seth - Would the CSV be an easier route when it comes to emailing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your own function to determine the largest item in each column and then create a suitable table:

```
def write_table(data):
    col_spacer = " | "      # added between columns
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    return '\n'.join(col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data)


techs = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9"];
table = [['Tech', 'Total', 'Average']]

for tech in techs:
    current_tech = get_ticket_count(FHD_start,BHN_end,tech)
    tech_total =  str(current_tech[0])
    tech_average = current_tech[1]
    table.append([tech, tech_total, tech_average])

print write_table(table)
```

Giving you:

```
Tech  | Total | Average
name1 | 69    | 17
name2 | 30    | 7
name3 | 0     | 0
```

As you are using spaces to pad out each row, you would need to ensure that the font being used to display the email is fixed width, otherwise it would still look wrong due to the proportional spacing.

Comment: Ok so I get this:
 `print write_table(table)
NameError: name 'write_table' is not define` when i run that.

Comment: Have you copied all the script?  `def write_table()` is at the top?

Comment: sigh. i promise i know how to computer. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate) package. It supports a lot of output formats and is quite easy to use

Example:

```
import tabulate
headers = ['Tech', 'Total', 'Average']
data = [['name1', 69, 17], ['name2', 30, 7], ['name3', 0, 0]]
print(tabulate.tabulate(data, headers, tablefmt='presto'))
```

And it will print this:

```
 Tech   |   Total |   Average
--------+---------+-----------
 name1  |      69 |        17
 name2  |      30 |         7
 name3  |       0 |         0
```

or, if you use, let's say `tablefmt='simple'`:

```
Tech      Total    Average
------  -------  ---------
name1        69         17
name2        30          7
name3         0          0
```

and so on

Comment: Without a clear example, this is better suited as a comment.

Comment: @Prune, yeah, sorry about that. I was actually aiming for a comment, but posted as an answer by accident somehow... I added the example